# Pandas split to several csv using groupby and saving it to the folders with the same name

Tags: python, pandas, os.path

I'm very new to Python, Pandas and programming overall, sorry in if this is a too stupid question.

Question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050455/pandas-split-data-frame-into-multiple-csvs-based-on-column-value) (I've used this for my code) but i want to take it one step further and to save all separated csv's to each individual folder with the same name.

What do i have right now:

```
# this one is used to split carriers csv files 
for i, x in carriers.groupby('Contact Account Name'):
     x.to_csv(root + '/' "{}.csv".format(i.upper()), index=False)
```

+

```
 for i, x in carriers.groupby('Contact Account Name'):
        p = os.path.join(root, "{}.csv".format(i.upper()))
        x.to_csv(p, index=False)
```

And it is saving grouped 'Contact Account Name' values in a root folder as separate csvs. But what i need is to save it to the folder inside a root folder, named as 'Contact Account Name' values.

I've tried several different methods of creating folders, but failed.

Data Frame:

```
  Contact Account Name
0 Mike
1 Jeff 
2 Todd 
3 Bill
```

How is it working right now:

It is creating csv's:

```
root/MIKE.csv
root/JEFF.csv
root/TODD.csv
root/BILL.csv
```

How i want it to be:

```
root/MIKE/MIKE.csv
root/JEFF/JEFF.csv
root/TODD/TODD.csv
root/BILL/BILL.csv
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check folder existence with [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) and use [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) to create the new one:

```
new_dir = os.path.join(root, "Contact Account Name")
if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
    os.mkdir(new_dir)

for i, x in carriers.groupby('Contact Account Name'):
    p = os.path.join(new_dir, "{}.csv".format(i.upper()))
    x.to_csv(p, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you really have to do is to add the `Contact Account Name` (i) to the `os.path.join` command -

So, the following should roughly work -
```

```
for i, x in carriers.groupby('Contact Account Name'):
    p = os.path.join(root, i, "{}.csv".format(i.upper()))
    x.to_csv(p, index=False)
```

```

See more here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Answer (score 0):

You can define your output directory outside your loop. You may, as below, wish to check whether it exists, creating the directory via `os.mkdir` if it does not exist.

```
# define output directory
output_dir = os.path.join(root, 'Contact Account Name')

# create the directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.mkdir(output_dir)

for i, x in carriers.groupby('Contact Account Name'):
    # create output path from output directory
    p = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{i.upper()}.csv')
    x.to_csv(p, index=False)
```

Note in the example above I use f-strings, available in Python 3.6+ and more readable / efficient.