# Pandas split data frames into multiple csv's based on value from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a question [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192633/python-pandas-split-a-data-frame-based-on-a-column-value) but I need some further steps. The thing is my file contains like 50k+ lines. Each line have 4 values "Indicator","Country","Date" and "value". I want to split my CSV based on country. I do not know how many countries there is so all countries with similar name should be in one CSV file and so on. The CSV file in not order either. I am using pandas and here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
def read_csvfile():
    df = pd.read_csv('ebola_data_db_format.csv', sep= ',')
    
    #remove the unneeded columns
    df = df[df['Country'] != "Guinea 2"]  
    df = df[df['Country'] != "Liberia 2"]
   
    #reset the index
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    print (df.head(10))

read_csvfile()
```

I want to be able to have a CSV file for every country so I can plot their data separately. Help please!

Answer (score 3):

You  can use groupby:

```
country_dfs = {k:v for k,v in df.groupby('Country')}
```

To save them in several csv files:

```
for k, v in df.groupby('Country'):
    v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv')
```

or from `country_dfs`:

```
for k, v in country_dfs.items():
    v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv')
```

Comment: After I group them how can I then split them into several csv depending on country? This is only to group not to split I guess

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dictionary comprehension`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) here:

```
dfs_dict = {j: df[df['Country'] == j] for j in df['Country'].unique()}
```

For saving `country-wise` data in `country` cdv's, do this:

```
for k, v in dfs_dict.items():
    v.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(k))
```

Comment: This will group my csv file into countries. But I want to be able to save data depending on country automatically. I don't want to manually access "Guinea 2" by `dfs_dict['Guinea 2']`. I want my data to be saved automatically to files names after the country for example "Guinea.csv" and so on. How can I achieve that

Comment: @Mayank Porwal Hi I tried the saving formula but it gave me an error "'dict' object is not callable", do you know how to solve this? Thanks!